# Look when a line will be touching a sphere

Tags: algorithm

I am writing a game and I want to know when the player (who is stationary and is determined by an x, y and z) can see the enemy with a starting position x, y and z. There are a few sphere-like structures in the arena and I don't want the player to see the enemy at first. The enemy will be moving at a constant speed. The position of the enemy is determined by Enemy(position) = Enemy(0) + time * Direction.

I have written some code according to this site (https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtinter1.htm) but it doens't seem to work.

I have for input 13 integers:

1. The Player-coördinate x, y and z (Px,Py,Pz)
2. The Enemy-starting-coördinate x, y and z (Ex,Ey,Ez)
3. The centre of the sphere x, y and z and its radius (Cx,Cy,Cz,R)
4. The components of the vector x, y and z (Vx,Vy,Vz)

I need to know when the player can see the enemy.

This is my code:

```
double findtime(int Px, int Py, int Pz, int Ex, int Ey, int Ez, int Vx, int Vy, int 
Vz, int Cx, int Cy, int Cz, int R)
{
double a = (Ex*Ex+ Ey* Ey + Ez * Ez);
double b = (2 * Ex*Vx + 2 * Ey*Vy + 2 * Ez*Vz);
double g = Vx * Vx + Vy * Vy + Vz * Vz;
double e= Ex * Px - Ex * Cx + Ey * Py - Ey * Cy + Ez * Pz - Ez * Cz;
double o= Vx * Px - Vx * Cx + Vy * Py - Vy * Cy + Vz * Pz - Vz * Cz;
double d= (Px - Cx)*(Px - Cx) + (Py - Cy)*(Py - Cy) + (Pz - Cz)*(Pz - Cz) - R * R;
double A = o* o- g* d;
double B = 2 * e*o- b* d;
double C = e* e- d* a;

if (A != 0)
{
    double D = B * B - 4 *A*C;
    double rootD = sqrt(D);
    double t1 = (-1*B + rootD) / (2 * A);
    double t2 = (-1*B - rootD) / (2 * A);
    if (t1 <= 0 && t2 > 0)
    {
        return t2;
    }
    else if (t2 <= 0 && t1 > 0)
    {
        return t1;
    }
    else
    {
        return min(t1, t2);
    }
}
else
{
    double ans = -C / B;
    return ans;
}
}
```

Comment: You did not tell us enough information. What is the trigger to player see the enemy? When the enemy is inside sphere?

Comment: The sphere is some sort of building and you can't see through it.